# Scrapy Getting specific value of element on 2nd Page from URL extracted from 1st Page

Tags: python, scrapy

I am working with scrapy, and one a single webpage everything is working as expected. If I want to take a link extracted from page 1 and then scrape page 2 from the link I extracted from page 1, it is then I run into trouble.

I have item variables, and I want one of these to equal the value of an element on the second page which is time item was published.

Below is my code and stack. I know I am definitely gone in a wrong direction but cannot get the return value following the scrapy documentation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Spider file

```html
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
import time
import datetime

from stack.items import StackItem


class StackSpider(Spider):
    name = "stack"
    allowed_domains = ["donedeal.ie"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.donedeal.ie/find/all/for-sale/Ireland/?sort=AGE+DESC&source=ALL&start=0",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        adverts = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="listing-info"]')
        for advert in adverts:
            ts = time.time()
            item = StackItem()
            item['county'] = advert.xpath('span[@class="county"]/text()').extract()[0]
            item['section'] = advert.xpath('span[@class="section"]/a/text()').extract()[0]
            item['price'] = advert.xpath('div[@class="price shadow-default rnd-corners-left"]/a/text()').extract()[0]
            pricelink = advert.xpath('div[@class="price shadow-default rnd-corners-left"]/a/@href').extract()[0]
            request = Request(pricelink,callback=self.parse_page2)
            item['other'] = request
            item['title'] = advert.xpath('div[@class="title"]/a/span/text()').extract()[0]
            item['timestamp'] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            yield item

    def parse_page2(self, response):
        newitem  = response.xpath('//*[@id="adage"]/span').extract()
        return newitem
```

Trace (For one iteration, error repeats for every object)

```html
2015-03-26 12:40:36+0000 [stack] ERROR: Error processing {'county': u'Dublin',
         'other': <GET http://cars.donedeal.ie/cars-for-sale/audi-a4-2-0-tdi-120hp-se/8853726?offset=30>,
         'price': u'\u20ac12,950',
         'section': u'Cars',
         'timestamp': '2015-03-26 12:40:36',
         'title': u'Audi A4 2.0 TDi 120hp SE'}
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 62, in _process_chain
            return process_chain(self.methods[methodname], obj, *args)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 65, in process_chain
            d.callback(input)
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 382, in callback
            self._startRunCallbacks(result)
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 490, in _startRunCallbacks
            self._runCallbacks()
        --- <exception caught here> ---
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 577, in _runCallbacks
            current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy_mongodb.py", line 222, in process_item
            return self.insert_item(item, spider)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy_mongodb.py", line 251, in insert_item
            self.collection.insert(item, continue_on_error=True)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 409, in insert
            gen(), check_keys, self.uuid_subtype, client)
        bson.errors.InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: <GET http://cars.donedeal.ie/cars-for-sale/audi-a4-2-0-tdi-120hp-se/8853726?offset=30>

2015-03-26 12:40:36+0000 [stack] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-03-26 12:40:36+0000 [stack] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
        {'downloader/request_bytes': 273,
         'downloader/request_count': 1,
         'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
         'downloader/response_bytes': 19464,
         'downloader/response_count': 1,
         'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
         'finish_reason': 'finished',
         'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 26, 12, 40, 36, 72670),
         'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
         'log_count/ERROR': 30,
         'log_count/INFO': 8,
         'response_received_count': 1,
         'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
         'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
         'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
         'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
         'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 26, 12, 40, 35, 266551)}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    from scrapy import Spider
    from scrapy.selector import Selector
    from scrapy.http import Request
    import time
    import datetime

    from stack.items import StackItem

class StackSpider(Spider):
    name = "stack"
    allowed_domains = ["donedeal.ie"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.donedeal.ie/find/all/for-sale/Ireland/?sort=AGE+DESC&source=ALL&start=0",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        adverts = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="listing-info"]')
        for advert in adverts:
            ts = time.time()
            item = StackItem()
            item['county'] = advert.xpath('span[@class="county"]/text()').extract()[0]
            item['section'] = advert.xpath('span[@class="section"]/a/text()').extract()[0]
            item['price'] = advert.xpath('div[@class="price shadow-default rnd-corners-left"]/a/text()').extract()[0]
            pricelink = advert.xpath('div[@class="price shadow-default rnd-corners-left"]/a/@href').extract()[0]

            item['other'] = request
            item['title'] = advert.xpath('div[@class="title"]/a/span/text()').extract()[0]
            item['timestamp'] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

            request = Request(pricelink,callback=self.parse_page2)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request

    def parse_page2(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['something']  = response.xpath('//*[@id="adage"]/span').extract()
        return item
```